# Java way to find loop structure

Tags: java, collections

```
S.No   Entry
1      jack
2      dummy
3      Jones 
4      jack
5      jack
6      dummy
7      jones
8      Jones
```

The above table can be understood like,

```
Jack{
  Dummy
}Jones

Jack{
    Jack{
     Dummy
   }Jones 
}Jones
```

Am trying to find out whether a Jones is available for each jack. (i.e) for each open brace (jack) a close brace (Jones) should be available.

If Jones is not available the S.No should be returned like below,

```
Jack{
  Dummy
}Jones

Jack{
  Jack{
    Dummy
  }here Jones is missing 
}Jones
```

The output should be S.No5..which doesn't have a Jones.

What would be the best way to implement this logic. 
I tried counting and manipulating it but finding the S.no was not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this either recursively or iteratively with a stack data structure.

For the iterative approach, make a stack that stores the position of `jack` entry.

The stack would change as follows (top is on the left)

```
Entry    Stack  Result
jack     [1]    empty
dummy    [1]    empty
Jones    []     1
jack     [4]    1
jack     [5, 4] 1
dummy    [5, 4] 1
Jones    [4]    5
Jones    []     4
```

When you see `jack` you store its position on the top of the stack. When you see `Jones` you pop the stack, and assign the number to the result.

If the last `Jones` were missing, stack changes would look like this:

```
Entry    Stack  Result
jack     [1]    empty
dummy    [1]    empty
Jones    []     1
jack     [4]    1
jack     [5, 4] 1
dummy    [5, 4] 1
Jones    [4]    5
```

Now the result is 5, because 4 remains sitting on the stack after we run out of list entries.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a missing `jones` it is not necessarily possible to determine where it is missing from, because the structure is ambiguous. The best you can do is limit it to a range of possibilities.

```
String[] tokens = { "jack", "dummy", "jones", "jack", "jack", "dummy", "jones", "jones" };
int depth = 0;
List<Integer> open = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if (tokens[i].equals("jack")) {
        depth++;
        open.add(i);
    } else if (tokens[i].equals("jones")) {
        depth--;
        if (depth == 0) open.clear();
        if (depth < 0) throw new RuntimeException(
            "jones without corresponding jack at position " + (i + 1));
    }
}
if (depth > 0) {
    StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder("jack without corresponding jones at position ");
    for (int i = 0; i < open.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0) error.append(" or ");
        error.append(open.get(i) + 1);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException(error.toString());
}
System.out.println("OK");
```

If you remove one of the last `jones`es it will say `"jack without corresponding jones at position 4 or 5"` (1-based index, to match your example).